# Filter dataset for path element in D3js (v3)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, filter

I'm using a dataset to draw points and path elements with D3js. The dataset contains undefined values that I want to be filtered. I know how to filter the point elements but don't manage to filter the dataset for the path elements like area and line. I want to draw an area and line only based on the actual values, so I have to filter the undefined elements. My dataset looks like this:

```
ds = [
{x: 0, param1: 230, param2: 1070},
{x: 2, param1: 190, param2: undefined},
{x: 5.5, param1: 161, param2: 1207},
{x: 8, param1: 167, param2: 1165},
{x: 11, param1: 154, param2: 987},
{x: 12, param1: undefined, param2: 876},
{x: 12.32, param1: 187, param2: undefined},
{x: 15, param1: 156, param2: undefined},
....
];
```

I know how to filter a dataset to draw circle elements in a scatterplot (simplified version):

```
group.selectAll("circle")
    .data(ds)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")  
    .filter(function(d) {return d.param1 != undefined} )
    .(...);
```

I've tried the following code for the area:

```
var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) {return x(d.x);})
    .y0(h-padding)
    .y1(function(d) {return y(d.param2);});
group.append("path")
    .attr("class","area")
    .datum(ds)
    .filter(function(d) { return d.param2 != undefined})
    .attr("d",area);
```

I think I'm using the filter function in an incorrect way. I've tried to add the filter to the variable declaration of the area, but I didn't work either. For the line element I got the same problem.

The SO examples that I studies are all about filtering circle/dots (e.g.) elements. I didn't find anything about filtering path elements.

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: `.filter()` is for ........ **selections**, use `Array.filter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much easier to do the filtering before you bind the data to the DOM, rather than trying to transform it after you've drawn elements, etc. You can use a standard array filter to remove the undefined data points from your data set:

```
array.filter( function(d){ // your filter code here } )
```

In context:

```
group.selectAll("circle")
    .data( ds.filter(function(d) {return d.param1 != undefined}) )
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
```

The same principle applies for the area plot:

```
group.append("path")
    .attr("class","area")
    .datum( ds.filter(function(d){ return d.param2 != undefined }) )
    .attr("d",area);
```

Data is much easier to manipulate before it is bound to the DOM, so do as much cleaning and filtering as you can beforehand.

Comment: @i alarmed alien thank you, i will adjust it in my code